# Fatal error: Call to a member function limitPage()

Tags: magento-1.9

I was trying to add the pagination in one of my custom modules and i followed some reference URLs. Everything is good but at last i am getting an error Fatal error: Call to a member function limitPage() on a non-object in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php on line 516

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $this->getCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection_Db();
        $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
        $rowObj->setData($this->getOrderProductCollection());
        $this->getCollection->addItem($rowObj);
        //$this->getCollection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection);
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection->setPageSize(10);
        $this->getCollection->setCurPage(2.8);
        ///$this->getCollection->load();
        return $this;
```

Comment: This line`$this->getCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection_Db();` is very strange. And I can't find `limitPage` in your code example.

Comment: I am using setter and getter like  $this->setOrderProductCollection($productsCollection); where $productsCollection is an array not an object. That's why I created an instance of collection array. I got this error after this code $this->setChild('pager', $pager);